# Traceback with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I downloaded beautifulsoup4 through the command portal, but I'm having issues doing some web scraping assignments because I am always getting a Traceback saying that BeautifulSoup is not defined. Here's the beginning of my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

Any help to get past that line is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to import it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 0):

use pip to install it:

```
pip install bs4
```

and then import it into your program with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```